# Query a bigger file server for files and folders with get-childitem

Tags: windows, powershell, get-childitem, fileserver

I have a big file server more than 15 TB of files and folders, and I need to get all full names whith get-childitem, I am doing that:

$FSData = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\FS01 -Filter * -Recurse -Force

But the server consume of  memory is for 16GB, I wonder if there is any way to query and save to CSV without wait for the cmdlet finish memory dump.

Comment: You could use `robocopy` and its option `/L` to create a list of all files. It's probably even much faster.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using StreamWriter which will open the file only once and buffer input.  It managed to log all the filenames from my C:\ drive (925,232 files) in about 1 minute 15 seconds

```
$sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new('c:\temp\filelist.log');
$options = [System.IO.EnumerationOptions]::new()
$options.RecurseSubdirectories = $true
$options.AttributesToSkip = 0
[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFileSystemEntries('C:\FS01', '*', $options).ForEach( { $sw.WriteLine($_) }); 
$sw.Dispose()
```

Note EnumerateFileSystemEntries() returns both files and directories.  If you only want files use `[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('C:\FS01', '*', $options)`

Comment: Hey Daniel, Thanks for your help !!! I need to load some assemblys previously !?

Comment: All these commands will work immediately from PowerShell.  We are leveraging the power of .NET which is already present.  Nothing more to load

Comment: Hello Daniel, sorry for may delay to response... I have this message: https://ibb.co/mNF5J5h

I run Windows Server 2019, .Net Runtime 4.8 and PowerShell 5.1

Comment: Hello Daniel... Yesterday I run the script with PowerShell v7 and do it fine... But the process finish when the output had 5 000 000 of lines, maybe that is a 1/3 of my file server (totaly have 16TB)... Any sugesstion !?

Comment: The number of lines will be the sum of the amount of files, not the sum of the size of all the files which is what 16TB is.  Could you please run `dir c:\FS01 -File -Recurse | Measure-Object ` and check what the `Count` property shows?